# Replacing reversed words in string, from list

Tags: python, string, replace, character, slice

Python

I have list with reversed words:

```
['rab', 'milb']
```

And i have a string with these words:

```
foo(bar)baz(blim)
```

How can i replace this words on reverted?

That's what i do:

```
a = "foo(bar)baz(blim)"
reversed_w = ['rab', 'milb']
for i in range(len(reversed_w)):
    pure_k = a.replace(reversed_w[i][::-1], reversed_w[i])

print(pure_k)

# what i expect: foo(rab)baz(milb)
# what i get: foo(bar)baz(milb)
# it happens cuz after first iteration it "foo(rab)baz(blim)", but
# because i dont know how to "remmember" that state of that string,
# after second iteration i get "foo(bar)baz(milb)", 
# cuz i am making that operation with unedited 
# string: "foo(bar)baz(blim)".
```

Ofcourse i can do it with slices, but its bruteforce. Imagine if i had 50 reversed words, and 1000 characters long string

I have searched replace in for loops, but didnt find anything

Comment: have you tried just `a = a.replace(...)` and then `print(a)`?

Comment: bruh, forgot it. thats what i needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue arises because you're resetting `pure_k` in each iteration of the loop. Instead, you should update the string `a` itself or use another variable to keep track of the changes across iterations:

```py
>>> a = "foo(bar)baz(blim)"
>>> reversed_w = ['rab', 'milb']
>>> for word in reversed_w:
...     a = a.replace(word[::-1], word)
... 
>>> print(a)
foo(rab)baz(milb)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use regex:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(.*?)\((.*?)\)")
all_matches = pattern.findall("foo(bar)baz(blim)")
# [('foo', 'bar'), ('baz', 'blim')]
```

Here, what we are doing is creating a capture group to capture anything that looks like this:

```
func_name(argument)
```

Which, of course, `foo(bar)` and `baz(blim)`  match. Then we get the matches as a list of 2 tuples, where the first element is the function name and the second is the argument.

Then you can do your reversal:

```
result = ""
for func_name, arg in all_matches:
    result += func_name + "(" + "".join(reversed(arg)) + ")"
print(result)
# 'foo(rab)baz(milb)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `format` with a `dict`-mapping substitution.

Assumed that normal brackets are used to delimit the words to substitute and that curly brackets are not allowed (are reserved for the substitution, otherwise need to be escaped).

```
a = "foo(bar)baz(blim)"
rwords = ['rab', 'milb']

word_mapping = {w[::-1]: f"({w})" for w in rwords}
new_a = a.replace('(', '{').replace(')', '}').format(**word_mapping)
```

or with a single substitution using the staticmethod `str.maketrans`

```
mapping_for_substitution = str.maketrans(dict(zip("()", "{}")))
new_a = a.translate(mapping_for_substitution).format(**word_mapping)
```